# How can i know if an array of CGPoint is close to another array of CGPoint?

Tags: ios, ios6, nsmutablearray, uibezierpath, cgpoint

I have a UIBezierPath made of an array of CGPoint´s using the function addCurveToPoint, here is a little of the code:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[path setLineWidth:10];
[path moveToPoint:pts[0]];
for(int i = 0; i<[array count]; i++) {
     [path addCurveToPoint:[array objectAtIndex:i] controlPoint1:pts[1] controlPoint2:pts[2]];
}
```

When a touch is recognized on the view, i get the point of the touch and i need to compare it to the GCPoint´s of the UIBezierPath and say if it is inside of the UIBezierPath or not. What i have used is the function containsPoint but it didn´t work, here is my code:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(p.x, p.y);
    NSLog(@"actual point x %f y %f", point.x, point.y);

    if ([path containsPoint:point]) {
        NSLog(@"it contains the point");
    }
}
```

At the end, i need to get all the set of the touched points and say if the touched points are inside of the UIBezierPath(or most of them) and add a margin error so the touch doesnt need to be so precisely, also how can i say how far is the point of the UIBezierPath?

Comment: What do you mean by "containsPath does not work"? It should work. Note that the bezier path must be *closed* for the test.

Comment: Do you mean using [path closePath]?

Comment: Yes, exactly. (It is mentioned in the `containsPoint:` documentation.)

Comment: It works, but i have to be so precisely with the touch, is there anyway to set an offset? or something like that, i mean like a margin of error

Comment: *That* I do not know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath` to create a thickly stroked version of your path (for example, with `lineWidth` set to 22).  Then test whether the point is inside either of that stroked path or your original path.

[Ole Begemann: CGPath Hit Testing](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/cgpath-hit-testing/)

Comment: let me try this solution